# Driver Out of memory - due to Brodcasting

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory

I came to know that Driver out of memory can also happen due to broadcasting.

During broadcasting, smaller table/dataframe is copied/broadcasted to all executors memory on worker nodes. How does out of memory can happen in driver node during Broadcasting, does driver also copies same data in driver memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this jira [SPARK-17556](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17556) attachments and comments.

**Currently in Spark SQL, in order to perform a broadcast join, the driver must collect the result of an RDD and then broadcast it.** This introduces some extra latency. And of course can cause OOM in the driver.

It might be possible to broadcast directly from executors (the work is in progress).

Comment: got it. Does driver just collects the data, broadcasts to all executors or driver also keeps a copy of broadcasted data as mentioned in another answer by @drome?

Comment: @Matthew It should keep for future use because it may be needed for new executors. Also Node can be lost and some executors lost, then new will start